# Angular 4; "show more" in table cell when there is a lot of characters

Tags: angular

I've got such a code structure:

```html
<mat-table>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="messageText">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      {{ 'CUSTOMER.MESSAGES_LIST_TABLE.MESSAGE' | translate }}
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{row.messageText}}
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

It's a fragment of table.

Let's assume that I have some content in mat-cell. If the content is too long (for example when content reaches 100 digits), I'd like to add "show more" span into mat-cell so I can click on it and expand this table cell to show remaining content.

Do you have any suggestions how to do it? My first thought is to grab element (like in jQuery - `$("mat-cell)`, put some conditionals (content.length > 100) and add "show more". Then add on.click to "show more" and expand mat-cell height.

I'd like to emphasize that I'm new in Angular so I will be grateful for simple answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

the key is

- Your row must have two properties messageText and e.g.showAll:boolean
- using *ngIf="row.showAll" you can hide-show a button "showMore" or a button "showLess" and row.messageText or row.messageText.substring(0,100)
- the button only toggle the variable row.showAll

You can make a Pipe also