# show part of a text and then with a "read more" show the rest instantly angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to show only 50 characters of a text, and then "read more" than if I click I will show the full text, I'm doing it in angular2 and I'm trying to do it in typescript, I leave the code I have.

HTML:

```
    <table width="200px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="el_div">
                    uno dos tres cuatro cinco seis siete ocho nueve diez once doce trece catorce quince dieciseis diecisiete dieciocho diecinueve
                    veinte
                    uno dos tres cuatro cinco seis siete ocho nueve diez once doce trece catorce quince dieciseis diecisiete dieciocho diecinueve
                    veinte</div>
                <br />
                <div style="font-family:Courier New;font-size:8pt;color:Blue;cursor:hand" onclick="gestionarTexto(this);" id="mas">Leer más</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'produccion',
   styleUrls: ['./produccion.scss'],
   templateUrl: './produccion.html'
})
export class Produccion {

  constructor() {
  }

  texto_original: string;
  gestionarTexto(div) {
      if (div.innerHTML == 'Volver') { this.contraer(); div.innerHTML = 
      'Leer más'; }
      else { this.expandir(); div.innerHTML = 'Volver' }
  }
  contraer() {
    this.texto_original = document.getElementById('el_div').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('el_div').innerHTML = 
    this.texto_original.substring(0, 50) + '...';
  }
  expandir() {
    document.getElementById('el_div').innerHTML = this.texto_original;
  }
}
```

If you can lend me a hand, because it does not work for me, I do not know if the HTML or TYPESCRIPT part is wrong.

Comment: In "angular way" create a Custom Pipe to acheive you want

Comment: Can you give me an example pls

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: if you not want to use a directive check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471229/angular-4-show-more-in-table-cell-when-there-is-a-lot-of-characters/47472175#47472175

Comment: mmm ok thanks I try :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using angular pipe.

**HTML:**

```
<table width="200px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="el_div" >{{strText | showChar:togglePipe}}</div>
                    <button *ngIf="strText.length > 50" (click)="showMoreText()">{{togglePipe ? "Show More" : "Show Less"}}</button>
                <br />
                <!-- <div style="font-family:Courier New;font-size:8pt;color:Blue;cursor:hand" (click)="gestionarTexto(this);" id="mas">Leer más</div> -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Component.ts**

```
strText:string = "uno dos tres cuatro cinco seis siete ocho nueve diez once doce trece catorce quince dieciseis diecisiete dieciocho diecinueve veinte uno dos tres cuatro cinco seis siete ocho nueve diez once doce trece catorce quince dieciseis diecisiete dieciocho diecinueve veinte";
  togglePipe: boolean = true;
  showMore: boolean = true;
  showMoreText() {
    this.togglePipe = !this.togglePipe;

  }
```

**pipe.ts**

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: 'showChar'
})
export class showCharPipe implements PipeTransform{

    transform(value:string,togglePipe:boolean): string {
        if(value.length > 50 && togglePipe){
            return value.substring(0, 50) + '...';
        }else{
            return value;
        }


    }

}
```

All the best buddy

Comment: Glad to help you